# Hierarchical mixed model to include correlation for features on the same level in R

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models, hierarchical

I currently have a data frame in place for the triggering value of software log messages triggering each other. All features are categorical. The data frame looks as follows

| From_Microservice | From_component | From*message*type | To_Microservice | To_component | To*message*type | Excitation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Service 1 | Component 1 | type 1 | Service 1 | Component 1 | type 1 | 10.4 |
| Service 1 | Component 1 | type 2 | Service 1 | Component 2 | type 2 | 4.2 |
| Service 2 | Component 2 | type 2 | Service 2 | Component 2 | type 3 | 0.5 |
| Service 2 | Component 2 | type 4 | Service 1 | Component 1 | type 2 | 0.0 |

message types are within components, which are within microservices. Furthermore, each row entry is unique in the sense that we have one, and only one, excitation value for 'messages of a certain type on a component on a Microservice', triggering 'messages of a certain type on a component on a Microservice'. It should be noted  that in this setup,  message type 2 on component 1 is precisely the same message type as message type 2 on component 2. The same holds for a component of a microservice.

I now want to run a hierarchical mixed model in R to see how each of the six features ('from_micoservice', 'from_component', etc) contribute to the total variance. Using the lme4 package, I modeled

```
mymodel <- lmer(excitation ~ (1|from_microservice) + 
                             (1|from_microservice:from_components) + 
                             (1|from_microservice:from_components:from_message_type)+
                             (1|to_microservice) + 
                             (1|to_microservice:to_components) + 
                             (1|to_microservice:to_components:to_message_type), data = df)
```

Although this model captures the hierarchical structure, it fails to incorporate the correlation between features of the same level, i.e. (`from`*`_microservice, to`*`_microservice`), (`from`*`_component, to`*`_component`), (`from`*`message`*`type`*`, tomessage`*`type`). This correlation should definitely be included as excitations on the same level, (ie same microservice, component or message type) naturally tend to higher.

My question is therefore: "How do I include the correlation between features on the same level?"